# React key cant add to element

Tags: reactjs, key

Im new to React and feeling shy to ask this question,but I dont know why that when I try to bind key to li element,Icant find it after rendering DOM.
Which looks like:

```
<ul><br />
  <li>I dont know why</li><br />
  <li>cant find the key</li><br />
</ul><br />
```

in console.
And I got 'undefined' with e.target.getAttribute('key') in click event.
Here my code (a simple todolist):

```js
  class Write extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.handle=this.handle.bind(this);
    }
    handle(){
      const text=document.getElementById('todoIn').value;
      this.props.onWriteDown(text);
    }
    render(){
     return (
     <div>
    <input type="text" id="todoIn" />
     <button onClick={this.handle}>confirm</button>
     </div>
     );
    }
  }

 class Todolist extends React.Component {
     constructor (props) {
      super(props);
      this.n=0;
      this.state={list:[]};
      this.todolist=[];
      this.handle=this.handle.bind(this);
      this.handle_del=this.handle_del.bind(this);
    }
    handle (m) {
      this.todolist.push({thing:m,vid:this.n++});
      this.setState({list:this.todolist});
    }
    handle_del (e) {
      var d = this.todolist.forEach((v,i)=>{
         if(v.vid==e.target.getAttribute('key')){
           return i;
         }
      });
      this.todolist.splice(d,1);
      this.setState({list:this.todolist});
    }
    render(){
      var that = this;
      var todo=[];
      //here I create React Element for each todo and bind some attribute BUT ONLY CLICK EVENT is ACCESSIBLE.I JUST WONDER...
      this.state.list.forEach(function(v,i,a){
       let temp=<li  key={v.vid.toString()} onClick={that.handle_del} >{v.thing}</li>;
        todo.push(temp);
      });
      return(
      <div>
        <Write onWriteDown={this.handle} /> 
        <ul>
        {todo}
        </ul>
       </div>
      );
    }
  }

   ReactDOM.render(
      <Todolist />,
     document.getElementById('root')
   );
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

`key` is used internally so React knows which components have been added, changed or removed. 
Also, keys don't get passed through.

For more information check ReactJS's doc.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Comment: ^ yup. You shouldn't be trying to do stuff with an element's key anyway. If you want some kind of unique identifier for a list element add one yourself (just don't name the prop `key`)

Comment: I learnt this part and find that I has misunderstood the meaning of key before.Thank you.And I  find that none of the  self-defining attribute can be seen in the rendered DOM,no matter they are set as a string or put in the {}.Are they all discarded by React ?What could we do if we need or want to set selt-defining attributes.

Comment: It depends on which attributes you are talking about. Usually, ReactJS components can handle most of the commons scenarios without the need of self defining attributes.

Comment: it seems right...It would be better to set the data as part of an object rather then an attribute in the html.

Answer (score 0):

As said in Hemerson's answer, you shouldn't be attempting to access the `key` attribute, it isn't passed through, and is only used as an internal reference to the object.

Instead, you can write your code as so:

---

```
let id = v.vid.toString();
let temp=<li key={id} onClick={() => that.handle_del(id)}>{v.thing}</li>;
```

---

```
handle_del (id) {
  var d = this.todolist.forEach((v,i)=>{
     if(v.vid==id){
       return i;
     }
  });
  this.todolist.splice(d,1);
  this.setState({list:this.todolist});
}
```

Comment: Thanks.It helps me.Just now I try locally and when the code went to forEach() ,d is undefined and I realize that I had made a mistake in my code.I did some changed,  and thing goes ok.                                                                     
   let d =0;                   
   this.todolist.forEach((v,i)=>{
         if(v.vid==id){
           d=i;
         }
      });